# How to get the innermost value among dictionaries at one go?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'00.Life': help}
help ={'A.Death':['dying','dead','mourir','pass away']}
```

I have one dictionary inside the other one.
How to get the innermost value at one go?

I hope I could just input 'dying'(one of the elements in the list) to get ['dying','dead','mourir','pass away'] list.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it "at one go" using your existing data structure. You will have to either iterate all the values, or construct a reversed, lookup dictionary first. For example:

```
>>> my_help ={'A.Death':['dying','dead','mourir','pass away']}
>>> my_dict = {'00.Life': my_help}
>>> lookup_dict = {k: v for v in my_dict["00.Life"].values() for k in v}
>>> lookup_dict["dying"]
['dying', 'dead', 'mourir', 'pass away']
```